# Count occurences of a set in a list

Tags: code-golf, set-partitions

Given a non-empty set of strings and a list of strings, find out how many times the set occurs in the list, i.e. how many times you could create the set with items from the list. Every element from the list can only be used once.

> Hint: a set is an unordered list of unique items.

Default [input/output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.

No external libraries allowed. Compiler/Interpreter standard libs are okay. This is code golf, so shortest solution counts.

---

Test cases:

```
["apple", "banana"], ["apple", "pear", "apple", "banana", "banana"] => 2

["apple", "banana"], ["apple", "pear", "apple", "banana", "apple"] => 1

["apple", "banana", "pear"], ["apple", "banana", "kiwi", "apple"] => 0

["coconut"], [] => 0
```

---

**EDIT:** removed a sentence stating that the input params are defined in local scope. This contradicts the default IO rules linked above.

Comment: Yes that clarifies it.  However I am a little hung up on the third sentence.  What do you mean by "doesn't handle objects"?

Comment: @WheatWizard some languages are not object-oriented and don't know the concept of comparing arbitrary objects.

Comment: You should probably change that to object-oriented because every language I am aware of does handle objects of some type even if objects are a closed class.  I should also point out that there are a good deal of languages that also cannot handle strings at all.

Comment: @WheatWizard okay, updated description. That paragraph was meant for languages such as C, Assembler or Maple.

Comment: What languages are object oriented? What should they use if not strings? I think the easiest thing would be to restrict to just strings. Or, alternatively, only integers. See [this advice](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8437/20260) on using the simplest type that suffices.

Comment: Good point, @xnor. updated. I think the solutions so far are all handling strings just fine, so this won't invalidate any.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork nope! will add another test for that.

Comment: The set is non-empty. The list can be empty.

Comment: OK, I would suggest to explicitly add that. Like *"Given a non-empty set of strings and a potentially-empty list of strings"* or similar, because as it's currently written my brain reads it as both the set and the list are non-empty.

Comment: For future reference, I'll also direct you to the [Sandbox](http://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can post challenges, get meaningful feedback, and tweak them before they're posted to main.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork thanks. much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Three fruit pies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59192/20260)

Answer (score 12):

## Python, 30 bytes

```python
lambda s,l:min(map(l.count,s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQrJNjlZuZp5GbWKCRo5ecX5pXolOsqfm/oCgzr0QhTSNaKbGgICdVSUdBKSkxDwiVYnUUkAQLUhOLQDS6KiT1mlxUMAwihGyWgY6CoY6CiRHICChbR8FIRwHEjtX8DwA)

Comment: Nice one. Didn't think about using map. You can save a little by using print instead of defining a lambda BTW.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Changing the `lambda` to a `print` brings the byte count up to 37 because of the two `input()`s required.

Comment: @WheatWizard as stated in the challenge, consider the inputs defined in local scope. You are NOT required to have the inputs explicitly defined, e.g. as function params or user inputs.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak if there is no good reason for it, you should not overwrite our [defaults for taking input and output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/64121) and our [defaults for codegolf submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/64121)

Comment: @ovs oh, I wasn't aware of that post. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ċ@€Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@k2@FR05qHO5v@//@vlFhQkJOqpKOglJSYB4RKSCIFqYlFIBpdCYIFAA)

The first argument of the program is the set, and the second argument is the list.

**Explanation**

```
ċ@€Ṃ
ċ@   -- Create a link which finds the number of occurrences of 
          its left argument in its right argument (the list)
  €  -- Map this link over each element in the first argument
          of the program (the set)
   Ṃ -- Minimum value of this.
```

*-1 byte thanks to @ETHproductions*

*-1 byte again thanks to @ETHproductions*

Comment: Very nice! You can save a byte by combining the links into one line: `⁹ċ$€Ṃ` I have a feeling that can be made shorter by using the implicit right argument in place of `⁹`...

Comment: I *think* `ċ@€Ṃ` works to save another byte... (the `@` reverses the arguments to `ċ`)

Comment: @ETHproductions Works correctly as far as I have tested.

Comment: It didn't exist until May 12 of last year, but `Ɱ` in place of `@€` (with reversed arguments to the program) saves yet another byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96ON6x7ubPr//79SYkFBTqqSjoJSQWpiEYiGCyQl5gEhEus/hhwA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁼þSṂ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@occ/hfcEPdzb9//8/Wj2xoCAnVV1HPSkxDwjVY5GEClITi4AUmgqEUgA)**

#### How?

```
⁼þSṂ - Main link: list theSet, list theList
 þ   - outer product using the dyadic operation:
⁼    -     is equal? (non-vectorising)
  S  - sum (vectorises) (yields the number of times each element of theSet appears in theList)
   Ṃ - minimum (can only make the minimum as a multiple)
```

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

```
f=(n,h)=>Math.min(...n.map(c=>h.filter($=>$==c).length))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#@59mq5Gnk6Fpa@ebWJKhl5uZp6Gnp5enl5tYoJFsa5ehl5aZU5JapKFia6dia5usqZeTmpdekqGpaf0/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTSNaKbGgICdVSUdBKSkxDwiVYnUUkAQLUhOLQDS6KiT1mppcVDMTIkSMkTBzUI1GSGZnlmeimPgfAA)

Comment: Save 2 bytes by using an anonymous function and another by currying the parameters: `n=>h=>Math.min(...n.map(c=>h.filter($=>$==c).length))` for 53 bytes

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

```
(s,l)=>l.map(e=>m[s.indexOf(e)]++,m=s.map(e=>0))&&Math.min(...m)
```

Assumes both `s` and `l` are arrays of objects. Uses JavaScript strict equality for comparisons, so for instance `[] === []` is false.

Comment: Very interesting solution. Please return or print the result. AFAIK this returns an anonymous function.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak The code as shown evaluates to an anonymous function. When called, the function returns the count as desired.

Answer (score 4):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>37</s> 34 bytes

Thanks to @Laikoni for shaving off three bytes.

```
s#l=minimum[sum[1|y<-l,y==x]|x<-s]
```

Call with `(set::[a]) # (list::[a])` where `a` is any type deriving `Eq`.

Comment: Instead of  `length[y|y<-l,y==x]` you can use `sum[1|y<-l,y==x]`.

Comment: @Laikoni, are you sure about that? I think I would need to use something like `sum[1|y<-l,y==x,_<-y]`, which comes out to two bytes longer—I could definitely be missing something there, though

Comment: Never mind, you're definitely right. Good call.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
q~f{\e=}:e<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19Yl1Ydk2pba5Vq8/9/tFJiQUFOqpKCUlJiHhAqxSoghApSE4uAFJoKhFIA)

**Explanation**

```
q~           e# Read and eval the input
  f{\e=}     e# Map each item in the set to the number of times it appears in the list
        :e<  e# Find the minimum of the resulting list
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Min[#/.Rule@@@Tally@#2]&
```

Pure function taking two lists as arguments in the suggested order and returning a nonnegative integer. `Tally` counts how many occurrences of every symbol occur in the input list, and `#/.Rule@@@` converts each element of the input set into the corresponding number of occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, 62 <s>59</s> bytes

Previous version didn't work for sets with no matches

```sql
select top 1(select count(*)from l where l=s)from s order by 1
```

With s and l as tables and columns named the same as the table

```sql
select top 1         -- return only the first result
    (select count(*) -- count of rows
     from l          -- from table l
     where l=s)      -- for each l equal
from s               -- to each from s
order by 1           -- sort by count ascending
```

Answer (score 3):

### Swift, 39 bytes

```
s.map{w in l.filter{$0==w}.count}.min()
```

explanation:

`s.map{}` goes through each word in s and will produce an array of counts

`w in`  names the mapped word for use in the next filter

`l.filter{}` aplies a filter to the l array

`$0==w` is the filter condition matching word w

`.count` gives the number of elements of l that met the condition

`.min()` returns the lowest count in the mapped result

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I've added code formatting for your solution. You can do this by prepending 4 spaces to lines that contain code.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
⌊/+/⎕∘.≡⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog-classic#e9TRnvb/UU@Xvrb@o76pjzpm6D3qXAhk/X/U0f4/jcvc0NTyUc829WilxIKCnFQlHQWlgtTEIhANF0hKzANCJFasOjZ9CElSjYUIkWUqwpDszPJMIg2DuQbVUBQtyfnJ@XmlJUAlAA)

`⎕` get evaluated input (list of strings)

`⎕∘.≡` get evaluated input (non-empty set of strings) and create equivalency table

`+/` add across

`⌊/` minimum across

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>203</s> 201 bytes

*Thanks to @Quentin for saving two bytes!*

```
#import<vector>
#import<string>
using T=std::vector<std::string>;
int f(T S,T L){for(int j,b,i=0;;++i)for(auto s:S){for(b=j=0;j<L.size();++j)if(L[j]==s){b=1;L.erase(begin(L)+j);break;}if(!b)return i;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#pY6/bsMgEIfn8hSULKBYUbsG20/gLd7aDuDg6JwYLP60Ui2e3cV2o6adIvUYDn738emmDfSDsT5/V403tkTXt/MW9KlEwaWG68L5436/Qvly/wY4Au1xS2t8yGpcsbE1ls5Rl8kMiifOt1tgcyiCN9jtDysiiy4Nu7zaOfhUlCWsY9DS6qV7KwrHRlk882qnrHCKSnUCTSuWEC6tEmceE/oomVU@WI2BxzhtQDeXcFQ4B5OWU6Ivl916kf4yNCKcalm9McHjPE9bj0QMw0WRDBMpdDokZvgmHJSwc/9L3fBsNpFXTdADXuq/4jW623uV/fb/DM/wAXdoG9MYHfyiiYyjOH0B)

Comment: `L.begin()` -> `begin(L)` saves one byte :)

Comment: Also, `using T=std::vector<std::string>;` saves another! Who knew modern pretty syntax could also help golfing.

Comment: @Quentin I tried that at first. Probably there was some simple typo I didn't notice.

Comment: Suggest `j<L.size()&!b;++j)if(b=L[j]==s)L.erase(begin(L)+j);` instead of `j<L.size();++j)if(L[j]==s){b=1;L.erase(begin(L)+j);break;}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>37</s>  18 bytes

### 37

```perl6
{+(($_=@^a⊍@^b)≽@a)&&.values.min}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#pZFBSsQwGIX3OcVPkJIwmaIuXFg69BDuHEcy8ReKmSQ0yaiEHkDBI3mZuUiN1qIdcCUh5OflvY/wEj3C/qJUFdk9Q6FsNGFplYodGoUe6iEtGDu5rZuNPLy@NZstP7y8N5IXRbmXOqIvd63phxxuAvrg4bIGRgDYNZXOaaQC6FaavOiNgF@iQ9l9nseumf@ci3@yRinbz/5CTfk58ufyoX1sZ6TTiaSssiaGr@S3zisSc6NXuYqKOC0NLMZeKnJvu6mj5QrY2gtY67zxyaEKeMchZWzr4fgTmBeaC5h8@SnJlw473QtIepygXkGaHD0l/fAB)

Expanded:

```perl6
{
  +( # turn into a 0 if False

    (
      $_ =        # store into $_ the result of
        @^a ⊍ @^b # use the baggy multiplication operator
    ) ≽ @a        # is that the baggy superset of the set
  )

  &&          # if that is True

  .values.min # get the minimum value from the Bag in $_
}
```

See [Sets, Bags, and Mixes](https://docs.perl6.org/language/setbagmix) for more information.

---

### 18

```perl6
{@^b.Bag{@^a}.min}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#pZDBSgMxEIbveYohB9nFdKkePLhsKT5Db7ZCGkdZTJOwSWpLyLOvo2vQLXiSEGaYfPMR/ugRjneNatnhDFfKRhMWVqk4oFHooRvT@mnfPMhXqjI3h97kkch1QB883HdQMYDqkUvnNHIBfC8NHb4T8GvoUA6f9ZKa8be1@KdrGhF@85eq7M@VP49v/Xs/My2LSVllTQxfm9/zumWR4ttQFC1zWhq4nnJp2YsdSkaLFVRbL2Cr6eLJoQr4XEMibe/hMvHKC10LKBx9JfnG4aCzgKSnDroVpEJkzvL4AQ)

Explanation:

`@^b.Bag` create a [Bag](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Bag) from the values
`{@^a}` key into that Bag (returns a list of counts)
`.min` get the minimum value of the resulting list

---

Comment: Neat answers, but neither of these look like functions / complete programs

Comment: @JulianWolf I was under the impression that snippets were allowed based on the statements “Consider both inputs being defined in the current scope as s and l.” and “You don't need to define a function.” I went and edited it anyway.

Comment: Ah, you're completely right. That must've been edited into the question after I read it. In any case, I like the aesthetic of this version even more than the last—Perl's syntax will always be a mystery to me.

Comment: @JulianWolf This isn't really a good example of Perl 6 code. I would recommend seeing Ovid's 1hr talk [Perl 6 — Why People Are So Excited](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR9UdvxMAbo), or looking at the [Resources](https://perl6.org/resources/) tab on [Perl6.org](https://perl6.org).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion. This is my first chllenge and I didn't know there already are rules for input and output. I changed it because most answers were using these rules even while it wasn't required.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Those are default rules, you could have specifically stated that _snippets were also allowed_. (Don't do it after people have posted golfs)

Answer (score 2):

## Axiom, 42 bytes

```
f(a,b)==reduce(min,[count(x,b)for x in a])
```

test code and results

```
(28) -> f(["1","2"], ["1", "2", "1", "1", "7"])
   (28)  1
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(29) -> f(["apple","banana"],["apple","pear","apple","banana","banana"])
   (29)  2
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(30) -> f(["apple","banana"],["apple","pear","apple","banana","apple"])
   (30)  1
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(31) -> f(["apple","banana","pear"],["apple","banana","kiwi","apple"])
   (31)  0
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 74 Bytes

```
<?foreach($_GET[0]as$v)$t[]=array_count_values($_GET[1])[$v];echo+min($t);
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b547f48335cb3dc8eb502a528ef481c069d2cd9c)

## PHP, 108 Bytes

```
<?[$x,$y]=$_GET;echo($a=array_intersect)($x,$y)==$x?min(($a._key)(array_count_values($y),array_flip($x))):0;
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a33ac8d1b9f8409f25dddbd733dcd162344d51bb)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 36 bytes

```
f=(n,h)=>n.Min(c=>h.Count(x=>x==c));
```

`n` and `h` are `string[]` and the output is an `int`.

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PCmbMW)

This answer is inspire by @ovs and @Alberto Rivera's logic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 135 bytes

```
int f(List<String> s,List<String> l){int n=0,i=0;while(i<s.size()){if(!l.remove(s.get(i++)))break;if(i==s.size()){n++;i=0;}};return n;}
```

This is my first code golf challenge and answer, so not sure about the format. Does it need to be a full compiling program? Do I need to define the parameters? Suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT**: wrapped code in a function. Thanks @Steadybox

Comment: An answer can be a [full program, a function or some other function-like construct](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/61405). You can take [the parameters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for example as arguments to a function or from standard input.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
hS/LF
```

Takes the list first and the set second.
[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hS%2FLF&input=%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22pear%22%2C+%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%2C+%22banana%22%5D%2C%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22pear%22%2C+%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%2C+%22banana%22%5D%2C+%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%5D%0A%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22pear%22%2C+%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%2C+%22apple%22%5D%2C+%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%5D%0A%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%2C+%22kiwi%22%2C+%22apple%22%5D%2C+%5B%22apple%22%2C+%22banana%22%2C+%22pear%22%5D%0A%5B%5D%2C+%5B%22coconut%22%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
    F  Expand the input into l and s (not literally, 
                  since those are function names in Pyth, but...)
   L   for d in s:
  /        Count instances of d in l
   L   Package all the results as a list
 S     Sort the results smallest-first
h      grab the smallest element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
v²y¢})W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@192aFPloUW1muH//0crJRYU5KQq6SgoJSXmAaFSLBeSWEFqYhGSHJIqAA)

```
v   }   # For each item in the first list...
 ²y¢    # Count the occurances in the second list.
     )W # Take the minimum occurrence count, return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 114 Bytes

```
<T>int a(Set<T>b,List<T>c){int m=2e32;b.stream().map(i->{int j=java.util.Collections.frequency(c,i);m=j<m?j:m;});return m;}
```

Tio coming soon

**Explanation**

- creates local variable m.
- maps the set to a stream.
- for each element, if the number of occurances of the element in the list is less than m, m is set to that value.
- returns m, which is the number of complete versions of the set

Answer (score 0):

### R, <s>61</s> <s>57</s> 44 bytes

```
print(min(sapply(s,function(x)sum(l%in%x))))
```

<s>Anonymous function.</s> Apparently you don't have to define a function for this challenge. *Saved 13 bytes thanks to count.*

Explanation:

`sum(l%in%x))` returns the number of times a string in `s` is found in `l`.

`lapply(s,function(x))` applies that to each string in `s` separately and returns a list of sums.

`min()` returns the smallest from that list.

Comment: Could be brought down to 40 Bytes with a for-loop: `z=c();for(i in s)z[i]=sum(l%in%i);min(z)`

Comment: Or even further to 37 bytes with sapply: `min(sapply(s,function(x)sum(l%in%x)))`

Comment: Brilliant, I always forget you can sum booleans. I'll edit that in later. I've been told I need that print() if it's not a function.

Answer (score 0):

**R 54 Bytes**

```
f<-function(s,l) min(table(factor(l[l%in%s],levels=s)))
```

Explanation: creating a table of the counts of only the values in the list that also appear in the sublist.

I then turn the variable into a factor in order to generate zeros if a value that appears in the sublist does not appear in the list. Finally, I take the minimum of the counts.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

```
a=>b=>a.reduce((x,y)=>(l=b.filter(s=>s==y).length)>x?x:l)|0
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=

a=>b=>a.reduce((x,y)=>(l=b.filter(s=>s==y).length)>x?x:l)|0

console.log(f(["apple","banana"])(["apple","pear","apple","banana","banana"]))
console.log(f(["apple","banana"])(["apple", "pear", "apple", "banana", "apple"]))
console.log(f(["apple","banana","pear"])(["apple","banana","kiwi","apple"]))
console.log(f(["coconut"])([]))
```